# How to get row index of ag-grid checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag-grid table that has checkboxes in each row. When I click a checkbox I want to be able to determine the index of the row.

I have tried:

```
  onRowClick(event: any): void {
    console.log(event.rowIndex);
}
```

and this sort of works but not really. If I click on the row I will get the index, however if I click on the checkbox in that row I will not get the index...kinda strange. I need to get the index of the row only when the checkbox is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you add the checkbox? Is it a custom cell component or is it a row selection checkbox?

Comment: It is a row selection checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For those looking, add this to your  tag in your HTML.

```
(rowSelected)="getRowIndex($event)"
[rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true"
```

In your ts file, add:

```
  public getRowIndex(event : any) {
    if(event.node.selected) {
      this.rowIndex = event.node.rowIndex;
    }
```